# How to view profile on Linux

Tags: files

I'm trying to do this part of my assessment:
*Show and explain the contents of the profile file.*

But I cannot open it. I tried `ls- profil`, but that didn't work.

Edit: Melebius helped me to find the answer. Thanks dude!

Comment: it aught to be `ls ~/.profile` (local version) or `ls /etc/profile` (global version)

Comment: Have you tried *anything*? How about a google search for "linux open file" or something? The `ls` command lists files, it doesn't open them. And that isn't even the right command for that. Please try to find an answer yourself before posting here.

Comment: It's a file, just like any other. Asking here is not against the rules at all! Your question is on topic here (Ubuntu is a Linux, after all). it's just that you show absolutely no effort here. For example, the command you say you tried, while irrelevant, would have given you an error message. Didn't that help at all? How do you show the contents of a file on Linux? Start with that. Find out how to do that and half the job is done already.

Comment: @CodingNewb2001 I feel curious to ask how googling could “not work”. I opened https://www.google.cz/search?q=How+to+open+profile+in+Linux, clicked on the first link, scrolled down to the answer: `vi ~/.profile` Isn’t it the solution?

Comment: My troll detectors are **tingling**. @CodingNewb2001 are you trolling us?

Comment: @Melebius post an answer if you feel like it.

Comment: I elaborated my comment to an explained answer. Thanks to @muru for notifying me that my Google search was so satisfying. :-)

Comment: I don't mind that you have gotten your answer. But be careful with your minus-rated questions. Stuff like this can score you a permanent ban on sites as these. Please *research* you questions better before posting them. You might even improve your questions *right* *now* to get the negativity off of you.  Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question. I mean it. Do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct filename of the current user’s profile is `~/.profile` (where `~` is a shortcut for the current user’s home directory).

You can use the command `cat` to just print the file out:

```
cat ~/.profile
```

For long files, the file viewer `less` can come in handy:

```
less ~/.profile
```

(Press <kbd>q</kbd> to quit `less`.)

Of course, you can open the file using your favorite editor, e.g. `vi` (a command-line based editor) or `gedit` (the default GUI text editor in Ubuntu) to view (and modify) it.

```
vi ~/.profile
gedit ~/.profile
```

(Type `:q` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to quit `vi`.)

Comment: +1 for the inclusion on how to quit `vi`. I love `vi` but it's hell and damnation for beginners. Most often I don't dare to mention it in my answers ;)